# Subject-verb agreement?

Tags: verb-agreement

Which verb form is correct?

> "Supporting fundraisers, like this one, goes a long way."

or

> "Supporting fundraisers, like this one, go a long way."

Is the verb pointing to 'fundraisers' or 'this fundraiser'?

Comment: I think the subject is "supporting".  Singular.

Comment: Remove the parenthetical and it becomes clear.

Comment: Eating cakes like this one are delightful???

Comment: The point is that clausal subjects take singular agreement.